# Linear independence of points under projection of Veronese re-embedding

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Let $V$ be a complex vector space.
Let $x_1,...,x_k\in PV$. Let $v_d: PV\rightarrow PS^dV$
be the Veronese. Then $v_d(x_1),...,v_d(x_k)$ are in general linear position
as long as $k\leq d-1$.
Now let $V=S^nW$ with e.g. $W=C^2$. Then
project $v_d(x_1),...,v_d(x_d)$ to $S^{nd}W$. Is there an elegant proof that
these points are in general linear position as long as $d$ is sufficiently large?
(I can see a brute force proof via a Vandermonde type matrix.)